# Authorized an org in VS Code but not getting "Deploy this source to org" option

Tags: salesforcedx, deployment, salesforcedx-cli

I authorized an org through VS Code, but at the bottom left it still says "No Default Org Set" rather than the org alias. I did this by running:
`sfdx force:auth:web:login --setalias vscodeOrg --instanceurl <my url here> --setdefaultusername` 
I don't have the option "SFDX: Deploy this Source to Org". Why is this?

I'm suspecting maybe something with my CLI. I can do `sfdx --version` but running `sfdx update` says `S3 host is not reachable`.

I read in another post that running `sfdx plugins:install @salesforce/sfdx-diff` can fix the issue and I tried this, and got:
`!    'ETIMEDOUT': connect ETIMEDOUT  Finished digital signature check. Installing... done`

Note: I tried setting the default org to the org I authorized. however, though it says "default org set", it doesn't show up on the bottom left. It still says "No Default Org Set".
An error that shows up though is
`defaultusername  This directory does not contain a valid Salesforce DX project. Add the --global flag to set config outside of a project.`

So, I tried running `sfdx force:config:set defaultusername=vscodeOrg -g` and it just printed out:

```
=== Set Config
NAME             VALUE
───────────────  ─────────
defaultusername  vscodeOrg
```

And nothing happened.

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange. What is your folder & file structure?  Can you add a screenshot of the entire left side (if your UI is default) of your VS Code Explorer - including your folder structure (with any sensitive folder or file names, if there are any, obscured) and including the bar along the bottom where it says "No Default Org Set"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Related to SFDX update, probably because its related to some of the issues SF is facing in last few days(Service disruption with DNS/ISP etc).

You can try -

```bash
sfdx config:set defaultusername=<user_name>
```

Reference - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_cli_usernames_orgs.htm

Comment: Should the username be the org alias or my org login username?

Comment: I tried this and it did not fix my `No Default Org Set` :(

Comment: actual username. For the aliases, it has different commands given in the link

Comment: with actual username or alias?

Comment: Just tried with username - it says `defaultusername  This directory does not contain a valid Salesforce DX project. Add the --global flag to set config outside of a project.`

Comment: I tried it with `--global` but it still says No Default Org Set..

Comment: If you're on VPN, try changing VPN maybe it allow to update sfdx

Comment: Interestingly, restarting VSCode fixed the issue. Thanks!